# filter function using tail recursion

Tags: filter, scheme, racket

Currently I have

```
  (define filter
    (λ (f xs)
      (letrec [(filter-tail
                (λ (f xs x)
                  (if (empty? xs)
                      x
                      (filter-tail f (rest xs)
                                        (if (f (first xs))
                                            (cons (first xs) x)
                                            '()
                                            )))))]
        (filter-tail f xs '() ))))
```

It should be have as a filter function

However it outputs as

```
(filter positive? '(-1 2 3))
>> (3 2)
```

but correct return should be (2 3)

I was wondering if the code is correctly done using tail-recursion, if so then I should use a reverse to change the answer?

Comment: Yes you need to reverse the result.

Comment: Does that apply to all tail-recursions?

Comment: Yes it does, unless you write a "reverse" procedure ;-)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: It is possible to implement a head sentinel or tail-modulo cons as you add to an accumulator, however just reversing it at the end is the most straightforward solution of the problem.

Comment: Lists are iterated from beginning to end and created from end to beginning. Thus a tail recursive copy would reverse the input.

Comment: "Does that apply to all tail-recursions?" no; you can use "surgical" list structure-mutating `set-cdr!` and keep adding new nodes at the growing list's end. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952631/849891) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256555/849891) for some example code, or [tag:tailrecursion-modulo-cons] in general.

Comment: This question is tagged <Racket>. Racket has no (really usable) mutable lists so the alternatives mentioned in the comments are not easily available and certainly not recommended.

Comment: @uselpa it is also tagged [tag:scheme]. -- Why aren't Racket's mutable lists usable?

Comment: In Racket, there's [`mlist->list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/mlists.html#%28def._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fmlist..rkt%29._mlist-~3elist%29%29). So you can tail-recurse along the list, adding each element at the end of the interim mutable list (with `set-cdr!` and `set!`), and then convert that mutable list back with an `mlist->list` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if the code is correctly done using tail-recursion.

Yes, it is using a proper tail call. You have

```
(define (filter-tail f xs x) ...)
```

Which, internally is recursively applied to

```
(filter-tail f
             (some-change-to xs)
             (some-other-change-to x))
```

And, externally it's applied to

```
(filter-tail f xs '())
```

Both of these applications are in tail position

> I should use a reverse to change the answer?

Yep, there's no way around it unless you're mutating the tail of the list (instead of prepending a head) as you build it. One of the comments you received alluded to this using `set-cdr!` (see also: *[Getting rid of set-car! and set-cdr!](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2007/11/getting-rid-of-set-car-and-set-cdr.html)*). There may be other techniques, but I'm unaware of them. I'd love to hear them.

---

This is tail recursive, requires the output to be reversed. This one uses a named let.

```
(define (filter f xs)
  (let loop ([ys '()]
             [xs xs])
    (cond [(empty? xs) (reverse ys)]
          [(f (car xs)) (loop (cons (car xs) ys) (cdr xs))]
          [else (loop ys (cdr xs))])))

(filter positive? '(-1 2 3)) ;=> '(2 3)
```

Here's another one using a left fold. The output still has to be reversed.

```
(define (filter f xs)
  (reverse (foldl (λ (x ys) (if (f x) (cons x ys) ys))
                  '()
                  xs)))

(filter positive? '(-1 2 3)) ;=> '(2 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [*"difference-lists"*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/difference-lists/info) technique and [curried functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), we [can have](http://ideone.com/sWodW7)

```
(define (fold c z xs)
   (cond ((null? xs) z)
         (else (fold c (c (car xs) z) (cdr xs)))))

(define (comp f g) (lambda (x)     ; ((comp f g) x)
  (f (g x))))

(define (cons1 x) (lambda (y)      ; ((cons1 x) y)
  (cons x y)))

(define (filter p xs)
  ((fold (lambda (x k)
           (if (p x) 
               (comp k (cons1 x))  ; nesting's on the left
               k))
         (lambda (x) x)            ; the initial continuation, IC
         xs)
    '()))

(display (filter (lambda (x) (not (zero? (remainder x 2)))) (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
```

This builds

```
                   comp
              /            \
           comp           cons1 5
        /        \
     comp       cons1 3
    /     \
  IC     cons1 1
```

and applies `'()` to it, constructing the result list in the efficient *right-to-left* order, so there's no need to reverse it.

First, `fold` builds the difference-list representation of the result list in a tail recursive manner by composing the consing functions one-by-one; then the resulting function is applied to `'()` and is reduced, again, in tail-recursive manner, by virtues of the `comp` function-composition definition, because the composed functions are nested *on the left*, as `fold` is a *left* fold, processing the list *left-to-right*:

```
( (((IC+k1)+k3)+k5) '() )        ; writing `+` for `comp`
  => ( ((IC+k1)+k3) (k5 '()) )   ; and `kI` for the result of `(cons1 I)`
  <= ( ((IC+k1)+k3) l5 )         ; l5 = (list 5)
  => ( (IC+k1) (k3 l5) )
  <= ( (IC+k1) l3 )              ; l3 = (cons 3 l5)
  => ( IC (k1 l3) )
  <= ( IC l1 )                   ; l1 = (cons 1 l3)
  <= l1
```

The size of the function built by `fold`  is *O(n)*, just like the interim list would have, with the reversal.