# How can I prevent a tail recursive function from reversing the order of a List?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I am experimenting with the functional `List` type and structural sharing. Since Javascript doesn't have a [Tail Recursive Modulo Cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization, we can't just write `List` combinators like this, because they are not stack safe:

```js
const list =
  [1, [2, [3, [4, [5, []]]]]];


const take = n => ([head, tail]) =>
  n === 0 ? []
    : head === undefined ? []
    : [head, take(n - 1) (tail)];


console.log(
  take(3) (list) // [1, [2, [3, []]]]
);
```

Now I tried to implement `take` tail recursively, so that I can either rely on TCO (still an unsettled `Promise` in Ecmascript) or use a trampoline (omitted in the example to keep things simple):

```js
const list =
  [1, [2, [3, [4, [5, []]]]]];


const safeTake = n => list => {
  const aux = (n, acc, [head, tail]) => n === 0 ? acc
    : head === undefined ? acc
    : aux(n - 1, [head, acc], tail);

  return aux(n, [], list);
};


console.log(
  safeTake(3) (list) // [3, [2, [1, []]]]
);
```

This works but the new created list is in reverse order. How can I solve this issue in a purely functional manner?

Comment: Are you asking to implement the "tail call modulo cons" implementation explicitly?

Comment: The easiest solution would be the `return reverse(aux(n, [], list))` from `safeTake`.

Comment: @Bergi I asked about an explicit TRMC on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50288939/6445533) yesterday.

Comment: @Bergi Personally I think the lack of TRMC is one of the biggest drawbacks of JS (not to mention TCO). But then again, I don't know any dynamic language that implements this optimization.

Comment: JS doesn't have immutable linked lists anyway, so it hardly would need TRMC. I guess you really want to use PureScript instead :-)

Comment: @Bergi I was hoping the interpreter would be smart enough to recognize when I use an array as a `List` type :D

Comment: @Bergi purescript? I rather explore how far I can bend Javascript towards functional style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laziness gives you tail recursion modulo cons for free. Hence, the obvious solution is to use thunks. However, we don't just want any kind of thunk. We want a thunk for an expression in [weak head normal form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). In JavaScript, we can implement this using [lazy getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters) as follows:

```js
const cons = (head, tail) => ({ head, tail });

const list = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, cons(4, cons(5, null)))));

const take = n => n === 0 ? xs => null : xs => xs && {
    head: xs.head,
    get tail() {
        delete this.tail;
        return this.tail = take(n - 1)(xs.tail);
    }
};

console.log(take(3)(list));
```

There are lots of advantages to using lazy getters:

1. Normal properties and lazy properties are used in the same way.
2. You can use it to create infinite data structures.
3. You don't have to worry about blowing up the stack.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is indeed very helpful! Is WHNF the underlying mechanism of what is sometimes referred to as guarded recursion in the Haskell community? I've been thinking guarded recursion would be a complex comppiler optimization. But now it seems it's essentially a side effect of lazyness.

Comment: WHNF is not a mechanism. Laziness is the mechanism. One way to think about it is that if laziness is a verb then WHNF is a noun. An expression in WHNF is one which has possibly only been evaluated upto the outermost constructor. The fields of the constructor might not have been evaluated yet (due to laziness). Therefore, laziness allows for expressions to be in WHNF. In turn, WHNF enables guarded recursion via implicit trampolining. Hence, by transitivity laziness gives you guarded recursion for free.

Comment: Note however, that laziness is not required for guarded recursion. For example, you can have guarded recursion in strict languages like Scheme. In this case, guarded recursion (i.e. tail recursion modulo cons) is indeed a complex compiler optimization.

Answer (score 2):

One way to prevent the list from reversing is to use continuation passing style. Now just put it on a trampoline of your choice...

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const identity = x =>
  x

const safeTake = (n, [ head = None, tail ], cont = identity) =>
  head === None || n === 0
    ? cont ([])
    : safeTake (n - 1, tail, answer => cont ([ head, answer ]))

const list =
  [ 1, [ 2, [ 3, [ 4, [ 5, [] ] ] ] ] ]

console.log (safeTake (3, list))
// [ 1, [ 2, [ 3, [] ] ] ]
```

Here it is on a trampoline

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const identity = x =>
  x

const call = (f, ...values) =>
  ({ tag: call, f, values })

const trampoline = acc =>
{
  while (acc && acc.tag === call)
    acc = acc.f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const safeTake = (n = 0, xs = []) =>
{
  const aux = (n, [ head = None, tail ], cont) =>
    head === None || n === 0
      ? call (cont, [])
      : call (aux, n - 1, tail, answer =>
          call (cont, [ head, answer ]))
  return trampoline (aux (n, xs, identity))
}

const list =
  [ 1, [ 2, [ 3, [ 4, [ 5, [] ] ] ] ] ]

console.log (safeTake (3, list))
// [ 1, [ 2, [ 3, [] ] ] ]
```

Comment: When I implement `safeTake` with `loop`/`recur` and apply it to a huge list I get a stack overflow at `answer => cont ([ head, answer ])`. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: @ftor, I added a trampoline demo above. Remember the `chainRec` question? I *think* it would be possible to rewrite this using our stack-safe continuation monad or by using a stack-safe `unfold`

Comment: Hm, this also seems to cause a stack overflow: [your example](https://repl.it/repls/SlategrayFreshCamel). Here is [my shot](https://repl.it/repls/PrizeCandidOutlier) from a few hours ago. I don't quite get it, but it seems as if the continuation winds up a real call stack as well.

Comment: @ftor added `call` to all return paths of `aux` – here's verification that [it works](https://repl.it/repls/VigilantRepentantExternalcommand) using a less clever test :D

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't have fixed that. I suck at CPS.