# Is there a difference in expressiveness of thunk or pair based deferred types?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, lazy-evaluation, thunk

Given are two types that both represent deferred computations:

```js
const deferThunk = thunk =>
  ({run: thunk});

const deferPair = (f, args) =>
  ({run: [f, args]});
  
const tap = f => x => (f(x), x);

const log = console.log;

const tx = deferThunk(
  () => tap(log) ("thunk based" + " " + "deferred computations"));

const ty = deferPair(
  ([x, y, z]) => tap(log) (x + y + z), ["pair based", " ", "deferred computations"]);

log("nothing happened yet...")

tx.run();
ty.run[0] (ty.run[1]);
```

An important difference seems to be that `deferThunk` leans towards a monad, whereas `deferPair` towards a comonad. I tend to prefer `deferPair`, because thunk execution is expensive in Javascript. However, I am not sure about possible downsides.

Comment: In [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969835/633183) to another one of your questions, I show that `call` gives you more control over the continuation by allowing you to pass arguments to it - this is more like `deferPair`. And [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306814/633183) to another one of your questions, using `call` here too. In the case of thunks, creating a new `() => ...` function wrapper is _necessary_, whereas `call` could use a lambda _or_ a function that's already been defined elsewhere ...

Comment: In [_another_ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473130/633183) to one of your questions, the deferred computation is encoded directly using a function, rather than an abstracted type. And finally, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45585629/633183) we see thunks are a more natural fit. So yes, there's a difference but I think that answer is a little obvious in hindsight. I think both are useful for expressing different programs.

Comment: `deferThunk` constructs a plain function, `deferPair` constructs a closure - a function with an environment. Given that every function in JS can be a closure anyway, there's not much of a difference between the two. What are you using them for at all?

Comment: @Bergi I use it to express some FP idioms that depend on non-strict evaluation and (along with Task) to separate the pure core of my Node.js program from the impure shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference in expressiveness of thunk or pair based deferred types?

No, there is no difference in expressiveness. Every function together with its arguments (i.e., a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))) is equivalent to a thunk, and every thunk is equivalent to a closure which accepts the unit type as input:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Control.Comonad

newtype Thunk a = Thunk { runThunk :: () -> a }

data Closure a = forall b. Closure (b -> a) b

runClosure :: Closure a -> a
runClosure (Closure f x) = f x

toThunk :: Closure a -> Thunk a
toThunk (Closure f x) = Thunk (\() -> f x)

toClosure :: Thunk a -> Closure a
toClosure (Thunk f) = Closure f ()
```

> An important difference seems to be that `deferThunk` leans towards a monad, whereas `deferPair` towards a comonad.

No, they are equivalent. Both `Thunk` and `Closure` have instances of `Monad` and `Comonad`:

```hs
instance Functor Thunk where
    fmap f (Thunk g) = Thunk (f . g)

instance Applicative Thunk where
    pure = Thunk . pure
    Thunk f <*> Thunk g = Thunk (f <*> g)

instance Monad Thunk where
    Thunk f >>= g = g (f ())

instance Comonad Thunk where
    extract (Thunk f) = f ()
    duplicate = pure

instance Functor Closure where
    fmap f (Closure g x) = Closure (f . g) x

instance Applicative Closure where
    pure a = Closure (pure a) ()
    Closure f x <*> Closure g y = Closure (\(x, y) -> f x (g y)) (x, y)

instance Monad Closure where
    Closure f x >>= g = Closure (runClosure . g . f) x

instance Comonad Closure where
    extract = runClosure
    duplicate = pure
```

> I tend to prefer `deferPair`, because thunk execution is expensive in Javascript.

Who said so? My benchmark shows that thunk execution is faster than closure execution:

```js
const thunk = () => 2 + 3;

const closureFunction = (x, y) => x + y;

const closureArguments = [2, 3];

const expected = 5;

const iterations = 10000000;

console.time("Thunk Execution");

for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    const actual = thunk();
    console.assert(actual, expected);
}

console.timeEnd("Thunk Execution");

console.time("Closure Execution");

for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    const actual = closureFunction(...closureArguments);
    console.assert(actual, expected);
}

console.timeEnd("Closure Execution");
```

---

> I can't follow your distinction between thunk and closure.

A thunk, in a strict language like JavaScript, is any function of the type `() -> a`. For example, the function `() => 2 + 3` has the type `() -> Number`. Hence, it's a thunk. A thunk [reifies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) lazy evaluation by deferring a computation until the thunk is called.

A closure is any pair of two elements where the first element is a function of the type `b -> a` and the second element is a value of the type `b`. Therefore, the pair has the type `(b -> a, b)`. For example, the pair `[(x, y) => x + y, [2, 3]]` has the type `((Number, Number) -> Number, (Number, Number))`. Hence, it's a closure.

> A thunk can have free dependencies too.

I'm going to assume that you meant free variables. Sure, a thunk can have free variables. For example, `() => x + 3`, where `x = 2` in the lexical context, is a perfectly valid thunk. Similarly, closures can also have free variables. For example, `[y => x + y, [3]]`, where `x = 2` in the lexical context, is a perfectly valid closure.

> I also didn't claim that there was no comonad instance for thunk.

You said that “`deferThunk` leans towards a monad, whereas `deferPair` towards a comonad.” The phrase “leans towards” makes no sense. Either `deferThunk` returns a monad, or it doesn't. Similarly for `deferPair` and comonads. Hence, I assumed that you meant to say that `deferThunk` returns a monad (but not a comonad) and vice versa for `deferPair`.

> Thunk doesn't have a context, so it is a bit weird to construct a comonad, right?

Why do you think that a thunk can't have a context? You said it yourself that “a thunk can have free dependencies too.” Also, no it's not weird to construct a comonad instance for thunks. What makes you think it's weird?

> Additionally, you use existentials to avoid the `b` on the LHS. I don't fully understand this, but it isn't compliant with my code, which uses a plain pair. And a pair gives context, hence the comonad instance.

I use a plain pair too. Translating the Haskell code into JavaScript:

```js
// Closure :: (b -> a, b) -> Closure a
const Closure = (f, x) => [f, x]; // constructing a plain pair

// runClosure :: Closure a -> a
const runClosure = ([f, x]) => f(x); // pattern matching on a plain pair
```

Existential quantification is only required to make the types check. Consider the `Applicative` instance of `Closure`:

```hs
instance Applicative Closure where
    pure a = Closure (pure a) ()
    Closure f x <*> Closure g y = Closure (\(x, y) -> f x (g y)) (x, y)
```

Because we used existential quantification, we can write the following code:

```hs
replicateThrice :: Closure (a -> [a])
replicateThrice = Closure replicate 3

laugh :: Closure String
laugh = Closure reverse "ah"

laughter :: Closure [String]
laughter = replicateThrice <*> laugh

main :: IO ()
main = print (runClosure laughter) -- ["ha", "ha", "ha"]
```

If we didn't use existential quantification then our code wouldn't type check:

```hs
data Closure b a = Closure (b -> a) b

runClosure :: Closure b a -> a
runClosure (Closure f x) = f x -- this works

instance Functor (Closure b) where
    fmap f (Closure g x) = Closure (f . g) x -- this works too

instance Applicative (Closure b) where
    pure a = Closure (pure a) () -- but this doesn't work
    -- Expected pure :: a -> Closure b a
    -- Actual   pure :: a -> Closure () a

    pure a = Closure (pure a) undefined -- hack to make it work

    -- and this doesn't work either
    Closure f x <*> Closure g y = Closure (\(x, y) -> f x (g y)) (x, y)
    -- Expected (<*>) :: Closure b (a -> c) -> Closure b a -> Closure b c
    -- Actual   (<*>) :: Closure b (a -> c) -> Closure b a -> Closure (b, b) c

    -- hack to make it work
    Closure f x <*> Closure g y = Closure (\x -> f x (g y)) x
```

Even though we can somehow get the `Applicative` instance to type check, it's not a correct implementation. Hence, the following program still won't type check:

```hs
replicateThrice :: Closure Int (a -> [a])
replicateThrice = Closure replicate 3

laugh :: Closure String String
laugh = Closure reverse "ah"

laughter :: Closure Int [String]
laughter = replicateThrice <*> laugh -- this doesn't work
-- Expected laugh :: Closure Int String
-- Actual   laugh :: Closure String String
```

As you can see, we want `(<*>)` to have the type:

```hs
(<*>) :: Closure b (a -> c) -> Closure d a -> Closure (b, d) c
```

If we had such a function then we could write:

```hs
replicateThrice :: Closure Int (a -> [a])
replicateThrice = Closure replicate 3

laugh :: Closure String String
laugh = Closure reverse "ah"

laughter :: Closure (Int, String) [String]
laughter = replicateThrice <*> laugh

main :: IO ()
main = print (runClosure laughter) -- ["ha", "ha", "ha"]
```

Because we can't do this, we use existential quantification to hide the type variable `b`. Hence:

```hs
(<*>) :: Closure (a -> b) -> Closure a -> Closure b
```

Furthermore, using existential quantification enforces the constraint that given `Closure f x` we can only use `f` and `x` by applying `f` to `x`. For example, without existential quantification we could do this:

```hs
replicateThrice :: Closure Int (a -> [a])
replicateThrice = Closure replicate 3

useReplicateThrice :: a -> [a]
-- we shouldn't be allowed to do this
useReplicateThrice = let (Closure f x) = replicateThrice in f 2

main :: IO ()
main = print (useReplicateThrice "ha") -- ["ha", "ha"]
```

However, with existential quantification the above program wouldn't type check. We would only be allowed to apply `f` to `x`, which is how a closure ought to be used.

Comment: I can't follow your distinction between thunk and closure. A thunk can have free dependencies too. I also didn't claim that there was no comonad instance for thunk. Thunk doesn't have a context, so it is a bit weird to construct a comonad, right? That's what i meant.

Comment: Additionally, you use existentials to avoid the `b` on the LHS. I don't fully understand this, but it isn't compliant with my code, which uses a plain pair. And a pair gives context, hence the comonad instance.

Comment: Edited my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: I skimmed over your edit - this is more I could have asked for, thanks. I'll dive into it later.

Comment: You just describe your `Closure` type you defined in your answer. But a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in Javascript and probably most other languages has completely different semantics.

Comment: Sure, but under the hood, every language defines closures the same way. To quote the article that you linked to, "A _closure_ is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared." The closure data type (which I described) is used to implement the closure language feature with which you're acquainted.

Comment: Also free variables don't represent context in the sense of a comonad. You can't take a free variable and provide it for the subsequent comonadic computation, you can just extract the result of a thunk by applying it and this result may depend on one or more free variables. There is `Env`, the comonadic version of the `Reader` and its context is the shared environment. But this very environement is missing with thunks, hence I think it is awkward to create a corresponding instance. Anyway, no offence.

Comment: Also, no. Closures don't have different semantics from what I described. It's just an expression (usually a function but it doesn't have to be) along with a lexical context (i.e., a mapping from names to values) for the free variables. The only difference is that my closure data type doesn't have free variables because they have been bound using function abstractions. Nevertheless, it's semantically equivalent because `(λ x. t) s` reduces to `t [x := s]` anyway, where `t` is an expression where `x` is a free variable.

Comment: A free variable is not a context. It's just a free variable. The context is the mapping from free variables to values, which is denoted by `b` in the pair of the type `(b -> a, b)`. Also, thunks do have a lexical environment. The only difference is that thunks use the lexical environment of JavaScript whereas the closure data structure also has its own lexical environment. There's nothing awkward about creating a `Comonad` instance of a thunk. It doesn't need to have an explicit environment like closures do. The comonad implementation of thunks doesn't require an explicit environment.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with pair based deferred computations and I think they are at least more flexible than their thunk-counterparts. Here is a stack-safe port of Haskell's fixed-point combinators to Javascript:

```js
// data constructor

const structure = type => cons => {
  const f = (f, args) => ({
    ["run" + type]: f,
    [Symbol.toStringTag]: type,
    [Symbol("args")]: args
  });

  return cons(f);
};

// trampoline

const tramp = f => (...args) => {
  let acc = f(...args);

  while (acc && acc.type === recur) {
    let [f, ...args_] = acc.args; // (A)
    acc = f(...args_);
  }

  return acc;
};

const recur = (...args) =>
  ({type: recur, args});

// deferred type

const Defer = structure("Defer")
  (Defer => (f, ...args) => Defer([f, args]))

// fixed-point combinators

const defFix = f => f(Defer(defFix, f));

const defFixPoly = (...fs) =>
  defFix(self => fs.map(f => f(self)));

// mutual recursive functions derived from fixed-point combinator

const [isEven, isOdd] = defFixPoly(
  f => n => n === 0
    ? true
    : recur(f.runDefer[0] (...f.runDefer[1]) [1], n - 1),
  f => n => n === 0
    ? false
    : recur(f.runDefer[0] (...f.runDefer[1]) [0], n - 1));

// run...

console.log(
  tramp(defFix(f => x =>
    x === Math.cos(x)
      ? x
      : recur(
        f.runDefer[0] (...f.runDefer[1]),
        Math.cos(x)))) (3)); // 0.7390851332151607

console.log(
  tramp(isEven) (1e6 + 1)); // false
```

Please note that not only the deferred type is based on pairs but also the incorporated trampoline (see line "A").

This isn't an ideal implementation but just a demonstration how far we can get with lazy evaluation in a strict language without tail call/tail call modulo x optimization. I apologize for asking too many questions on the same topic. Tenacity is an alternative strategy for gaining new knowledge, when someone lacks cleverness.